# Saving pdf stream in a file as a pdf

Tags: c#, .net, file, pdf, stream

I have a variable which holds a pdf stream , this variable is of type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream>`. I want to save this pdf stream in a pdf file but I am not sure how to do so . Below is a piece of code I tried to work on . Any ideas as to what I can try to save this stream in a file

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream> pdf = //Some logic here which gets a pdf stream
```

I want to store the pdf content in the variable in a file as  a pdf

For that I worote the method

```
public static void SaveStreamAsFile(string filePath, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream> inputStream, string fileName)
{

    string path = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
       // logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the input stream and write it to the output stream..

```
public static async Task SaveStreamAsFile(string filePath, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Stream> inputStream, string fileName)
{
    var stream = await inputStream;
    var path = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    var bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];

    await stream.ReadAsync(bytesInStream, 0, (int) bytesInStream.Length);

    using (var outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
       await outputFileStream.WriteAsync(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    }
}
```